# CefSharp Wpf , Session Cookie for multiple instances

Tags: wpf, cefsharp, chromium-portable

I am very curious if there is a possibility in CEF Sharp , somehow to isolate each instance of browser from other instances.

I am creating 4 instances of browser. Logging in on of the instances , 
immediately 3 other instances become logged in as well.

Is it possible to achieve somehow in Current version that we got from Nuget ?

Answer (score 9):

As of [revision 2040](https://github.com/roadlabs/chromiumembedded/issues/1044), CEF now adds support for complete isolation of storage and permissions (cache, cookies, localStorage, access grants, etc) on a request context basis. This is also now in CEFSharp.

To make sure that no sessions overlap between multiple instances, simply create a new RequestContextSettings object, set PersistSessionCookies and/or PersistUserPreferences to false, and assign it to your browser while creating a new RequestContext - I am not sure if setting them to false is completely necessary for multiple instances, maybe someone else can give some info on that.

```
//usually ChromiumWebBrowser setup goes above this

RequestContextSettings requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings();

requestContextSettings.PersistSessionCookies = false;
requestContextSettings.PersistUserPreferences = false;

webBrowser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings);
```

This had been giving me headaches for a while and this appears to finally solve that issue.

Comment: to add on to this- if i wanted to essentially use a different profile "folder" for each, so it could be persisted between sessions- where would this be set? thanks

Comment: I think i found it. 
RequestContextSettings.CachePath =  ""

Answer (score -2):

Just use this code, its working for me.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        CefSharp.CefSettings settings = new CefSharp.CefSettings();
        settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\CEF"; 
       CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);

        InitializeComponent();
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com/");
        browser.BrowserSettings.ApplicationCache = CefSharp.CefState.Disabled;

    }
```

Comment: Because he literally asked to "isolate each browser instance from others" but the answer you suggessted is complete opposite - setting custom folder for ALL instances in general.