# How to manage muti user profile with Cefsharp?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, user-profile

What is the best to manage multi-user profiles ??

I found that to create a new RequestContextSettings and to save into a specific folder was a possible way :
[CefSharp Wpf , Session Cookie for multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451702/cefsharp-wpf-session-cookie-for-multiple-instances)
Yet, that implies to do it before the CEFSettings initialization.

So, perhaps I have to shutdown the CEF, before changing user profile.
But how to manage that in a clean manner many times for a session of the appli ?
I read too the Cef.Shutdown Method is launched only one time
https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_Shutdown.htm

So, my question : in a current session, what is the way for a

```
RequestContextSettings lRCS = new RequestContextSettings();
requestContextSettings.CachePath = "another user";
myBrowser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(lRCS);
```

without getting an error message, saying that ' RequestContext must be set before the underlying CEF browser is created.'

Tx a lot for your help.

@amaitland 
Your help is really appreciated. This code is extract from [Request Context (Browser Isolation)](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown)

`var requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings { CachePath =  cachePath2};
 browser= new ChromiumWebBrowser("mysite.com");
 browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings, new CustomRequestContextHandler());`
and that raises 2 errors :
Code    Erreur CS1503   Argument 1 : impossible to convert 'CefSharp.RequestContextSettings'  to 'CefSharp.IRequestContext'

Code    Erreur  CS0246   type 'CustomRequestContextHandler' can't be found. (Missing using directive or assembly  référence ?)  .

But if I modify the last line, with only one parameter call

`browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings);`

I can run something, and I get cache datas in the cachePath2.  Yet, the screen stays in white if I do

`browser.CloseDevTools();
 browser.Dispose();
 var requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings { CachePath = cachePath2};
 browser= new ChromiumWebBrowser("mysite.com");
 browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings);`

or the browser stays with the previous page I had with the user1, if I don't add the CloseDEvTools + Dispose.

So I guess that the `CustomRequestContextHandler` is an important parameter to update the browser, and to not freeze it.
But I don't find how I can have complete assembly references.
I use VS2017, Winforms and Nuget package 71.0.2.
cef.redist.x86" version="3.3578.1870" targetFramework="net461"
Tx again for your help.

Comment: why not use separate windows accounts?

Comment: I use separate windows accounts, and I will save cache datas in those windows, so one cachePath for one profile, and so one requestContest for one account.

Comment: You have to create new `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance. Your statement about doing it before `CEFSettings initialization` is impossible. You can only `Initialize/Shutdown` once per process as detailed in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown

Comment: Tx for helping me.

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Comment: Please also specify the CefSharp version you are using

Comment: Sorry, I do as best as I can. This editor is not very user friendly, imo

Comment: Cefsharp is cef.redist.x86" version="3.3578.1870" targetFramework="net461"